# Matplotlib axline is vertical when it should be at an angle...until I change the dates/times for the chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, line

I'm trying to draw an angled line on a chart with Matplotlib, but there are times when it just draws a vertical line, incorrectly. It appears to be a problem with the dates/times. It's like there's a minimum time required between points before it will plot correctly. Can anyone shed any light on this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

time = 1652536320  # Start time
unix_time = [time]

for i in range(4):
    time += 16525
    # There must be 16526 seconds (4.5 hours) between unix timestamps for the axline to plot correctly.
    # Anything less incorrectly produces a vertical line.
    unix_time.append(time)

non_unix_time = []
for t in unix_time:
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    converted = mdates.date2num(dt)
    non_unix_time.append(converted)

print(unix_time)
print(non_unix_time)

fig = plt.figure()

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))

x = non_unix_time
y = [29675, 29813, 29840, 29761, 29746]

ax3.axline((non_unix_time[0], 29600), (non_unix_time[1], 29800))

ax3.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: To understand: when you run the code as you posted does it work or not? Because I ran it and it looks fine

Comment: Ah, sorry, yeah, I posted the code with it working. I've edited the code (changed time += 16526 to time += 16525). This is when it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is quite tricky to get without digging a bit deeper. When converted using `date2num`, timestamps become decimal numbers like `19126.661111111112`.

When drawing lines, `matplotlib` [checks whether the points are "close" in the coordinate space](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/9765379ce6e7343070e815afc0988874041b98e2/lib/matplotlib/lines.py#L1389) with respect to their magnitude using the [`np.allclose()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) function. If they are close, the slope of the line is automatically set to `np.inf` and a vertical line is drawn. Now, in your case you can indeed see that under your threshold difference of `16526` seconds, the points are considered "close":

```
import numpy as np

# Testing with non_unix_time[0] and non_unix_time[1].
# Same as: print(np.allclose(19126.661111111112, 19126.852372685185))
# Prints True. 
print(np.allclose(non_unix_time[0], non_unix_time[1]))
```

If you test with bigger differences, this will print `False`. The solution in your case is to use a single point and the `slope` parameter and calculate the correct slope yourself:

```
slope = (29800 - 29600)/(non_unix_time[1] - non_unix_time[0])

#ax3.axline((non_unix_time[0], 29600), (non_unix_time[1], 29800))
ax3.axline((non_unix_time[0], 29600), slope=slope)
```

And the line will be plotted correctly:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I was really struggling to understand that one. That's so helpful! :)